# Background image method in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, position

> Why is'nt the image appearing on my webpage? Can anyone explain me how it works and its solution please?

```
HTML:
<div class="bg-image"></div>

CSS:
.bg-image {
background-image:url("photo1.jpeg");
width: 400px;
height: 600px;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Is the image you are accessing in the correct place in your directory?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is in same folder then try this:

```
background-image: url("./photo1.jpeg");
```

If not then this:

```
background-image: url("../folder1/folder2/photo1.jpeg");
```

And make sure that there is no typo or extension error!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background-size: cover;` from your css. This should fix it

Answer (score 0):

i think your image location and pictures are at same folder and can you try this Css code?

```
background-image: url("../photo1.jpeg");
```

If you use folder add them after .// like that.

```
background-image: url("../images/photo1.jpeg");
```

Comment: They are in the same directory, and the image format is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with **img src** as

```
<div class="bg-image"><img src="photo1.jpg"></div>
```

or you can simply do it with:

```
background: url('photo1.jpg') cover no-repeat;
```